# minipage with tables

Tags: tables, minipage

If I have a minipage like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\centering
A
\medskip
B
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Why it is not possible to insert tables instead of A and B? If I try, I get "LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\centering
            \begin{table}[h]
                \centering
                \bgroup
                \def\arraystretch{1.2}
                \begin{tabular}{ c c | c | c | }
                    & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P2} \\
                    & & $a_1$ & $a_2$ \\
                    \hline
                    \multirow{2}{*}{P1} & $a_1$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
                    & $a_2$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \egroup
                \caption{Title}
            \end{table}
\medskip
            \begin{table}[h]
                \centering
                \bgroup
                \def\arraystretch{1.2}
                \begin{tabular}{ c c | c | c | }
                    & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P2} \\
                    & & $a_1$ & $a_2$ \\
                    \hline
                    \multirow{2}{*}{P1} & $a_1$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
                    & $a_2$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \egroup
                \caption{Title}
            \end{table}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Ideally, I would like to understand the meaning of "LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `table` environment cannot be part of a `minipage`. Use only
*one*  environment `table` and *no* minipage! Such an environment can have more than one caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{ c c | c | c | }
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P2} \\
    & & $a_1$ & $a_2$ \\    \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{P1} & $a_1$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
& $a_2$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Title}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ c c | c | c | }
                & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P2} \\
                & & $a_1$ & $a_2$ \\
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{P1} & $a_1$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
                & $a_2$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
                \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Title}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

fro two tabulars side by side use:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c c | c | c | }
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P2} \\
    & & $a_1$ & $a_2$ \\    \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{P1} & $a_1$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
& $a_2$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Title}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c c | c | c | }
                & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P2} \\
                & & $a_1$ & $a_2$ \\
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{P1} & $a_1$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
                & $a_2$ & 0, 0 & 0, 0 \\
                \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Title}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I would like these two tables to be side by side

Comment: no problem: Then put two minipages _inside_ the `table` environment. See edited answer in a minute.